# Does the Civi GoCardless extension use the GoCardless API?

Tags: api

We're a charity running CiviCRM 4.6 on Drupal 7. Last year, we moved all of our direct debits to GoCardless, which is running nicely. However, we're wanting to feed information from GoCardless back into Civi to state whether a recurring contribution has been paid or declined or cancelled, etc. At the moment, this is a very slow manual process, downloading a statement from GoCardless and then finding the corresponding contact in Civi line by line.

There's some information about the Civi GoCardless extension here (http://www.vedaconsulting.co.uk/gocardless), but this seems to be showing how to set GoCardless up as a payment processor.

Does anyone know if the GoCardless extension (or a different extension) can be set up in Civi to receive information back about contributions made through GoCardless, and if so, how does one go about configuring and running it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that the only way civi would know about the information automatically if is the payment was set up via a civi contribution page in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

My [GoCardless extension](https://github.com/artfulrobot/uk.artfulrobot.civicrm.gocardless) does this.

Each payment is automatically entered in as a contribution and if you cancel the subscription or the mandate, that's handled, too.

It relies on exposing a webhook that receives info from the GoCardless API whenever anything changes.

It's been in production use for 6 months now without a hitch, although see the [issue queue](https://github.com/artfulrobot/uk.artfulrobot.civicrm.gocardless/issues) for caveats to this. Also see [this issue about migration](https://github.com/artfulrobot/uk.artfulrobot.civicrm.gocardless/issues/4) which was parked since nobody seemed to want it, but you may need it.